# Does the substitution model work for closures? Or do you need an environment model?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, computer-science, lambda-calculus

Eg. Say this is our JavaScript code:

```
let a = x => {
  let y = x * 2
  return z => x + y + z
}
let b = a(1)
let c = b(2)
```

Can I evaluate this using a substitution model, or do I need an environment model?

I began like so:

```
let c = ((x => {
  let y = x * 2
  return z => x + y + z
})(1))(2)
```

But then I would need to evaluate the inner expression (called with `1`) before I can evaluate the outer expression (called with `2`). But for substitution it's always outside-in.

Is this an indication that the substitution model is inadequate here? Or is it kosher to eval inside-out as well as outside-in? Or is there some other way to look at it?

Comment: You don't need an environment model if your code doesn't mutate the bound scope variables.

Comment: In pure functions, order of evaluations doesn't matter. But even for outside-in, you have to evaluate the left hand side of the application operation to a function before being able to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution model works for closures. Basically you replace the bindings with their bound values. You don't need an environment model.

```
const b = a(1)                  // ==
const b = z => 1 + (1 * 2) + z

const c = b(2)             // ==
const c = 1 + (1 * 2) + 2  // ==
const c = 5
```

It's only if you really need to use `let` (in the event you actually rebind it) where you need an environment model.

When it comes to evalution order it's clear that in two calls like `a(1)(2)` you cannot do the second call with the argument `2` first since it is called on the result of `a(1)`. Thus you need to know the result of `a(1)` so you need to substitute that first, then do the next call on that result.

```
let c = (x => {
  let y = x * 2
  return z => x + y + z
})(1)(2)
// substituting 1 for x ==>
let c = (z => 1 + 2 + z)(2)
// substituting 2 for z ==>
let c = 1 + 2 + 2
```

Comment: I see. So what's the order of operations for substitution? Is the idea that it doesn't matter if you evaluate inside-out or outside-in, because either way you'll arrive at the same result?

Comment: @bcherny I've added to the answer.

Comment: I would have the second line be `let c = (let y = 1*2 in z => x + 1 + z)(2)`

Comment: @Bergi Better to just substitute it because that expression isn't valid JS the way you have written it and since the curlies are gone the scopre isn't obvious anymore.